# PHP mail error domain missing or malformed<EOL>

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer, heidisql

I'm trying to send a mail to a customers email thats set in my database.

```
$subject = 'Testing PHP Mail';
$txt = 'This mail is sent using the PHP mail function';
$headers = "FROM: test@gmail.com";
$query = ("SELECT email FROM ps_customer where id_customer = 2");
$result = $dbc->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['email'];
$to_email = (string)$row;

//while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
//    echo $row['email'];
//    $to_email = (string)'$row <@>';
    if (mail($to_email, $subject, $txt, $headers)) {
        echo "send";
    } else {
        echo "failed";
    }
```

this is my code that's need to send the email to the email out of the database.

but when i try to send it i get the error: **: domain missing or 
malformed**

Comment: `fetch_assoc` returns you an array. You are now putting that whole array (as a string) into the to address. My guess is you want something like `$row['email']`.

Comment: `(string)$row` returns word `Array`.

Comment: What do i need to change to dont get the whole array?

Comment: Question tags say you are using PHPMailer but your code doesn't even attempt to use that library. Can you please clarify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want the address, and it's the only field you're fetching, so I'd go with:

```
$query = ("SELECT email FROM ps_customer where id_customer = 2");
$result = $dbc->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$to_email = $row[0];
```

No need to use an assoc array for this.

You've not mentioned it, but the messages you send will probably be rejected. You're sending via `mail()`, which means you are not sending through gmail's servers, but you're using a gmail from address. This is forgery and will mean your messages will be bounced or spam filtered. You can't solve this using `mail()` (other than by not using gmail for your from address); you would need to [send using SMTP via gmail using PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) (that you tagged this question with).